# Missing understanding for pivot tables on Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, many-to-many, relationship

I know the relationship with table pivot, but i don't understand:

Is the pivot a table that **I** have to create on my database? Or is it a *virtual* table that laravel provides to us?!

Beyond that: is better use pivot relationship or use my own third table to relationship many to many?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely only need a pivot table for a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) Relationship, if it is a One to Many you would only need to include a foreign key. However, Laravel is flexible enough to allow you to do whatever you feel like doing as there is no right way to do anything in Laravel.

Personally, I would say it's better to stick to the best practices/conventions as you will find it easier to get help form the community than if you roll your own custom solution that no one else understands.

If you haven't already heard about [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com), it's a truly fantastic resource for building things with Laravel. I have been using Laravel for several years now and I still learn new things watching Jeffrey's videos.

If you can't afford the subscription, you can still watch each "What's new in Laravel" for free going back to Laravel 5.0 or further but I don't know how useful they would be. Which should give you a good overview of some of Laravel's best practices and conventions.

Jeffery also has a free series on [Learning Vue.js 2](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/1) which you should also look into and he'll get to using Vue together with Laravel.